# Easiest way to shorten directory?

Tags: command-line, bash, directory

I am aware this may be a duplicate, and if so, I will delete it.

What is the easiest way to navigate to a deep directory without having to type the directory every time. I do a lot of stuff in the same folders but every time I open a new terminal, I have to navigate to the directory again.

So far, I have been using variables in .bashrc, but is there an easier way than

```
cd $data
```

to get somewhere? For example, if I want to just be able to type "data" and be navigated to one of my data folders, how do I go about that?

Answer (score 3):

Just make an alias for the respective command in `~/.bashrc`.

```
alias data='cd /home/User/some_folder/another_folder/data/'
```

And run `source ~/.bashrc`. After that you can just type `data` in terminal and it will take you there

Comment: Tried to make an alias once before and couldn't get it to work. Seems to be working now. Thanks, partner.

Comment: @J.Doe  You're welcome. How were you making the alias before ?  There may have been quoting issue or something along those lines

Comment: That was my guess. Some small error like that. Do the initial and final / have to be included? If so, that could have been my error.

Comment: Final slash doesn't have to be included, but for initial it depends on what you mean. Initial has to be included if you are giving absolute path. If I'm talking  a directory called `my_stuff` that is in my home directory, then I'd give `cd /home/user/my_stuff`. If I am *already* in `/home/user` I can just do `cd my_stuff`, or a little better habit is to do `cd ./my_stuff` . For the alias in this question, which you want to run from anywhere, you have to do it with the absolute path.

Answer (score 3):

My first thought was what Sergiy posted, but an alternative is to create a symbolic link in your home directory:

```
ln -s data /long/path/to/deep/directory/data
```

Now you can just `cd data` ( from your home directory, otherwise it's `cd ~/data` ) when you want to get there.  This has the added advantage that if you open nautilus and want to go there graphically you can also just click on the data link in your home directory.

Comment: Nice idea as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use `cdable_vars`:

```
$ data=/tmp
$ shopt -s cdable_vars
$ cd data
/tmp
```

Or `autocd`

```
$ shopt -s autocd
$ $data
cd -- /tmp
```

From [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html):

> `autocd`
>   If set, a command name that is the name of a directory is executed as
>   if it were the argument to the cd command. This option is only used by
>   interactive shells.
>
> `cdable_vars`
>   If this is set, an argument to the cd builtin command that is not a
>   directory is assumed to be the name of a variable whose value is the
>   directory to change to.

It would have been brilliant if we could combine the two, but the two seem to be mutually exclusive in scope.